# threadgroup_barrier clears memory to 0

Tags: c++, gpu, gpgpu, metal

I have a very simple kernel, in Metal Shading Language, that uses shared (threadgroup) memory but which is not working, and I can't understand why. It just writes a value to shared memory, and then read and outputs it:

```
kernel void test_shared(
    uint thread_index [[thread_position_in_grid]],
    uint local_index [[thread_index_in_threadgroup]],
    uint group_index [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]],
    device float* output [[buffer(0)]],
    threadgroup float shared[32])
{
    float value = 1;
    shared[local_index] = value;
    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup); /// <-- important line
    value = shared[local_index];
    if(local_index == 0) output[group_index] = value;
}
```

I launch 100 threadgroups, each with 32 threads via this C++ code:

```cpp
void test()
{
    const unsigned int bufsize = sizeof(float) * 100;
    NS::SharedPtr<MTL::Buffer> buf = NS::TransferPtr(device.newBuffer(bufsize, MTL::ResourceStorageModeShared));

    MTL::CommandBuffer* cmd = queue->commandBuffer();
    MTL::ComputeCommandEncoder* encoder = cmd->computeCommandEncoder();

    encoder->setBuffer(buf.get(), 0, 0);

    encoder->setComputePipelineState(kernel_test_shared.get());
    encoder->dispatchThreadgroups(MTL::Size(100, 1, 1), MTL::Size(32, 1, 1));

    encoder->endEncoding();
    cmd->commit();

    cmd->waitUntilCompleted();

    const float* dat = (const float*)buf->contents();
    printf("buf =\n");
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        printf("    [%u] %f\n", k, dat[k]);
}
```

About the output at the end of `test()`:

- **Expected:** 1
- **Actual:** 0. It is 1 only if I remove the `threadgroup_barrier(...)`, but I suspect this would be the result of a compiler optimization.

**Why would the `threadgroup_barrier` seemingly clear the shared memory to 0?**

Comment: If you are gonna use thread group memory, you need to at least call `setThreadgroupMemoryLength`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. This is not obvious at all, given that its not explicitely said in the doc and I though the compiler could easily infer such information from source code... If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nope. Command encoder doesn't know this information and it doesn't know how you are gonna use that threadgroup memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use threadgroup memory, you need to use `setThreadgroupMemoryLength`.

I would also suggest explicitly specifying the `[[threadgroup(n)]]` binding point.

Comment: Isn't it `[[threadgroup(n)]]` instead ?

Comment: I think you are right, I was under the impression that `threadgroup` bindings take up buffer indices, but I think it's not. In the spec they are a different group, in section 5.2.1.